# python3 print \ with a single numeric value

Tags: python

I have got a requirement where I need to send a string having "\1" to some other device and it expects utf-8 format. but its getting printed in a weird format as shown below

```
print("*/\1/p".encode("utf-8"))
```

output in the device
[image]

I just want my string "\1" to print as "\1" when encoded in utf-8 format.

Comment: `encode()` returns the bytes representation of the object, not a string

Comment: `print(r'\1')` if you want the backslash to be literal.

Comment: the requirement is not clear, and i think just printing to console makes no sense, often such requirement comes from writing to file or some device. there should be more context.

Comment: Are you saying you want two characters, the backslash and a 1?

Comment: Unclear how data gets sent to device. Please show your complete code that sends the data and device's code that _receives the event_ as a [mcve]

Comment: Alternatively, you can see that `print("*/\1/p".encode("utf-8").decode("utf-8"))` doesn't print the 1 at all since you need to _escape the backslash_, as answered

Comment: In other words, How can I save/send/print such strings in string of bytes?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to escape the `\` character, and not encode:

```py
>>> print("\\1")
\1
```